# Head Lamp on Honda Shine

Tags: honda, electrical, motorcycle, headlight, shine-mc

I'm planning to change/modify the Headlight bulb. kindly suggest. My bike (Honda Shine) has 12V 3AH(MF) Battery & Head Lamp 12V 35W/35W halogen bulb. In rainy season & city Bye-pass roads the visibility is less. So i adjusted the angle its quite better comparability earlier. kindly suggest to improve more intensity(visibility).

1. shall i change the halogen bulb color(yellow) to Blue-white...which is available in same 35w range philips
2. is it possible to  replace it with a 60/55w halogen bulb. (color white)
3. is it possible to replace it with Xenon HID kits?? kindly suggest suitable one with complete accessories to buy like Do I need to install a relay, or rectifier and new wires?

Comment: You can put a bigger gauge wire and a higher amp relay. By doing this you will increase the effectiveness (brightness and range) and the life of the bulb. The lower (amps) the bulb burns the dimmer it shows, more orange-yellow. The higher the bulb burns the brighter it shows, more blue-white.

Answer (score 4):

The Honda Shine does not have a high amperage output stator like a larger motorcycle, think goldwing.  As Paulster2 so aptly put, less resistance in the wire the more amperage or 'flow' you get.

Taking that into consideration.  If you can increase the gauge of wire feeding your headlights you could go with your option number 2, which is to put a 60/55 halogen into which is plenty bright.

I would not put a HID kit into your bike, it will tax the charging system and battery and possible even lead to rectifier failures.

Comment: +1 for Ducatikiller who killed it here.. People do not understand the HID taxes the rectifier and will blow out the damn thing and by the time you notice the rectifier is broken your battery will be dead.