# Is it ok to put LED light for Hero Honda Splendor Head Light?

Tags: motorcycle, hero-honda, direct-bikes

Current Hero Honda Splendor headlight is very dim. So I want to put LED for headlight . Is there any effect on battery by doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things to consider when changing lighting:

**1) Draw on electrical system**

The draw should ideally be equal to the existing bulb. If it's greater, then you need to make sure the wiring is of a sufficient gauge to handle the load. Drawing more than the existing wires can handle is dangerous. Best case scenario you'll blow a fuse and your new bulb won't work. Worst case is you will overload the wiring, causing it to heat up and catch fire. If the wiring isn't sufficient, you'll need to run larger wire and use a relay to trigger the circuit. You'll also need to make sure the charging system on your bike is sufficient to provide the extra load.

**2) Heat**

Any energy not turned into light gets turned into heat. For this reason, the efficiency of the bulb is just as important as the draw. If you use a bulb that runs hotter than the stock bulb, you can run the risk of melting any plastic in the headlight assembly.

**3) Legal Requirements**

Different types of bulbs are meant for different enclosures. For example, HID bulbs are really designed to be used in projector housings that appropriately focus the beam. If you were to use an HID bulb in a housing meant for halogen bulbs, you can blind oncoming traffic. There are likely laws in your area dictating how much light is too much, how much is too little, and how it needs to be focused. How the bulb change affects other drivers and understanding local laws are your responsibility.

Comment: I will also add that for whatever reason, LED bulbs (especially all the cheap options available) don't "penetrate" as well as halogen or xenon bulbs. They  seem very bright at close range, but it can be very difficult to see the same distance down the road as the alternatives.

Comment: And one more addition, the charging system need to be sufficient. This thread suggests this might be an issue on your bike: http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/12859/head-lamp-on-honda-shine?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

You can opt for a bulb with the same wattage, with better energy rating. You can also opt for a higher wattage bulb, in which case, you may need an extra fuse. In any case, the answer to your question is : Yes, it's ok to swap bulbs, but do it with proper electrical knowledge.

Comment: How can a bulb with the same wattage yield a better energy rating? Could you clarify what you mean by "proper electrical knowledge"?

Comment: Zaid, wattage is a measure of consumption, but some bulbs/lamps are more efficient in converting electrical energy to light energy.  Therefore not all 55w bulbs/lamps are equal.  That being said, some locales (UK) legislate a maximum wattage for bulbs in an effort to reduce dazzling other drivers.  You may fall foul of the law if you exceed the legislative maximums.

Comment: @Zaid It would be interesting to rate bulbs in terms of "efficiency" ie the light output - which is measured in lumens and the power consumed measured in watts. Interesting that I have not seen any manufacturer do this...  As for "proper electrical knowledge" an understanding of cause and effect is one point, then power, volts, amps, resistance then you could continue with henrys, farads etc all relevant to motor vehicle repair

Comment: "You can also opt for a higher wattage bulb, in which case, you may need an extra fuse." You could very well need more than just a fuse. If the stock wiring isn't capable of handling the extra load, you'll need to run thicker wire. You also need to be careful with the headlight lens itself. LEDs generally are more efficient and run cooler, but an increase in wattage can lead to more heat, and not all vehicles are capable of dealing with that. I've heard stories of people melting their plastic headlight lens.

Comment: @SolarMike and Mauro Thank you very much for better explanations (than mine).

Comment: @raydowe Agreed. I probably should have put my thoughts in a better way.